# Why does super class assignment to subclass give an error?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, superclass

Can someone explain the reason why this has to give an error? - based on the way things are implemented in Java

Comment: Show a simple example of such code. http://sscce.org

Comment: *hint: add some code*

Answer (score 6):

Because all cats are mammals, but not all mammals are cats.

See the section title "Casting Objects" in [the Inheritance lesson of the Java Tutorial.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html)